# function Number() { [native code] } Error in JavaScprit

Tags: javascript, apex

I'm just trying to see my total amount of number variables with decimals but it's not working. My platform is Oracle Apex 20.2

```
var model = apex.region("itemig").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid").model;
console.log(model);
var amtKey = model.getFieldKey("ORAN");
//console.log(amtKey);
var totAmt = 0;
model.forEach(function(r) {
    var n_amount = parseInt(r[amtKey], 10);

    totAmt += n_amount;
    console.log(n_amount);
});

    $s('P705_TOTALORAN',totAmt);
```

Output was:

```
function Number() { [native code] }100507580901124105
```

What I want is to get the amount of numbers in `totAmt` with decimals. I'm not getting far because of this native code. Can someone tell me what it is and hopefully, more importantly I can complete this part in my work?

Comment: `totAmt = Number` and `n_amount = Number` just assign the global `Number` function to the two variables. It doesn't make them into numbers. What is that supposed to actually do, as it's just wrong. Was it supposed to be `0` instead?

Comment: It was var totAmt = 0; I just changed it and didn't work neither.

Comment: Also you have `var n_amount` twice in the code

Comment: what do you expect to get if you assign `Number`? i dont know maybe you want to defined types? then use typescript

Comment: You can use reduce instead of that forEach

Comment: Guys code is working only problem that there is no showing decimals total amount.That's why I'm trying to figure out it but not working.

Comment: If you want the decimals, don't use `parseInt()` as it literally parses an integer, i.e. strips away the decimals. Use `parseFloat()` instead.

Comment: or just `+r[amtKey]`

Comment: If it's returned NaN ?

Comment: Absolutely this should be more clear to understand and developers. When try it with toFixed method it worked but not completely. `parseFloat` or `+r[amtKey]` it returned NaN as Not a Number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is not a [typed language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing). The type of a variable is deduced using its value.

If you want to declare the variables `totAmt` and `n_amount` to be of type number, you should use `var`/`let` and assign a number to them:

```
var totAmt = 0;           // these two variables contain numbers..
var n_amount = 0;         // .. so they are of type "number"
```

Otherwise, if you do `var totAmt = Number;`, you are just assigning the global object [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) which is a native constructor for number objects, and when you add that using the `+` operator to another variable, the `toString` of that constructor will be called and that yields the string `"function Number() { [native code] }"` which is then concatenated to your other numbers:

```js
console.log(Number.toString());

console.log(Number + 5);
```

**Note 1:** If you want `totAmt` to be displayed with 2 decimal points then use [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) before you display it like so:

```
$s("P705_TOTALORAN", totAmt.toFixed(2));
```

**Note 2:** If the values `r[amtKey]` are decimal numbers, then `parseInt` will only get the whole-number part of those decimals. You should use `parseFloat`, `Number` or the unary `+` operator to parse the decimal part as well. Also, the `forEach` can be replaced by a `reduce` to shorten the code like so:

```
var totAmt = model.reduce(function(sum, r) {
  return sum + Number(r[amtKey]);               // Number will keep the decimal part of the number, whereas parseInt will only get the whole-number part
}, 0);

$s('P705_TOTALORAN', totAmt.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: It worked but not perfectly it's not showing decimals after comma only .00

Comment: @OnurSari because `totAmt` is a sum of integers (`var n_amount = parseInt(r[amtKey], 10);`), if they are decimals, use `parseFloat` or `Number` or simply cast them using the unary `+` operator like so: `var n_amount = +r[amtKey];`

Comment: @OnurSari check out **note 2**

Answer (score 1):

What `var totAmt = Number;` is doing is setting `totAmt` to the literal function `Number`, it does not tell JS that `totAmt` is supposed to be a number.

If you then add another number to it, it uses the `totAmt.toString()` method, which just returns `function Number() { [native code] }` and concatenates the number `n_amount` as a String to it.

When you remove the duplicate variable declaration, this code would work:

```
var totAmt = 0;
model.forEach(function(r) {
    var n_amount = parseInt(r[amtKey], 10);

    totAmt += n_amount;
    console.log(n_amount);
});
```

Also if you are adding numbers in an array up, JS has the `Array#reduce()` method for that, it makes your code much more concise:

```js
let totAmt = model.reduce((acc,cV)=>acc+cV[amtKey],0);
```

Comment: Reduce would be so much more elegant and terse

Comment: The problem is my code was like that exactly when i wanted to see decimals too my totAmt column in my grid its only shows amount without decimals.

Comment: @mplungjan not to mention idiomatic for a simple sum operation.